# No visible @interface for ____ declares the selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have set up a method in a separate class (called ExternalClass) that needs to take two arguments.

```
-(void) openImage:(NSDictionary *)payload InApp:(UIApplication *)app;
```

In my AppDelegate.m, I call the method like this:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)payload fetchCompletionHandler (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
    {
        [[ExternalClass sharedInstance] openImage:payload InApp:application];
    }
```

I am getting "No visible @interface for ExternalClass declares the selector 'openImage:InApp'

Any idea why?

Comment: you didn't import .h file?

Comment: I imported the .h file. Turns out it's an issue with my framework. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to declare this method in header(.h) file.

Declare this method in `ExternalClass.h` file.

```
-(void) openImage:(NSDictionary *)payload InApp:(UIApplication *)app;
```

And import this `ExternalClass.h` , where you want to use this method.

Comment: Ah, this wasn't actually the issue. But your suggestion helped me narrow down what the problem was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm trying to create a framework and use it in my app. It turns out none of the changes I made to any my framework methods were being reflected in my app. Thank you guys for pointing me in the right direction.